# Spring Framework: In a controller, get the model from different url

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, controller, annotations

I have a controller that contains two different request methods: POST and GET And they have different url mapping. I am trying to update a form on the view:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/sudent.do", method=RequestMethod.GET)
protected ModelAndView getStudent(ModelMap model, BindingResult result){
 Student student = new Student(); 
 .....
model.addAttribute("student", student);
return new ModelAndView("student"); }
```

and another method

```
@RequestMapping(value="/sudentUpdate.do", method=RequestMethod.GET)
protect ModelAndView studentUpdate(@ModelAttribute("student") Student student, Binding result) {..}
```

The models I am getting in these two methods are different.

With Spring Framework 4, is there a way to have the same model in two different method of the controller?

Thank you!

Comment: Alternatively you could take in the HttpServletResponse in your controller method and return a redirect.

Comment: Do you mean use HttpServletResponse to pass the model? How can I do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using `@SessionAttributes("..")` with the bean ID name worked for me